# Block other apps

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, smartphone

When developing for Android, I can create apps overlaying other apps or even blocking them.
Can I do such thing on windows 10 (mobile)?

Comment: Since windows wanted a 100% consistent user interface, applications can only use the notifications at the top.  Thus apps cannot overlay nor prevent notifications.

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible. You can upvote it on uservoice https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/14801112-add-overlay-ui-like-android or in the feedback hub.